# How do I use only one DataSet for the RDLC report designer as well as for the ReportViewer?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

When designing an rdlc report using the VS 2010 report designer, report items such as charts demand a dataset.  After designing the report, I add a ReportViewer to a webform, and it demands all of its own datasources.  How do I hook up the DataSet I have coupled to the report without duplicating the DAL functionality in the viewer page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Typed data-set to your project and add data-tables with schema as required in ReportViewer, generally the schema of data-tables would be that of views from database.

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx) on this.